# Sring @AutoConfigureRestDocs causes MockMvc port to change to 8080

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

A SpringBoot project with testing was working fine until I added `@AutoConfigureRestDocs`. Then the testing starting running on port 8080 where before there was no port that was apparent.

So, when I used to have

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/address/1")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
     .andExpect(jsonPath("$._links.self.href", is("http://localhost/employee/address/1")))
```

and it worked now it is failing with the error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$._links.self.href"
Expected: is "http://localhost/employee/address/1"
     but: was "http://localhost:8080/employee/address/1"
```

I've tried to change application.yml to add server.port: -1 and other things but I cannot control the port. I'm not even sure what to set it to though I suppose 80 would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the API of [AutoConfigureRestDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/restdocs/AutoConfigureRestDocs.html),you will see below description:
[image]

The default value of `uriPort` is *8080*, so you need to change it explicitly

```
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(uriPort = "80")
```